# How can I insert a shortcode into a php code in WORDPRESS?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a shortcode into a php code in wordpress. 
My code looks like this:

```
<h1 class="nd_booking_margin_top_50_responsive">'.__('Make Your Payment 
Here','nd-booking').' :</h1>
<div class="nd_booking_section nd_booking_height_30"></div>
<?php echo do_shortcode(“[pff-paystack id="1597"]”); ?>
```

I tried but the code is not showing on page.

Comment: The quotations you used `“ ”` are not valid syntax, try this: `<?php echo do_shortcode( '[pff-paystack id="1597"]' ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

you should try this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[pff-paystack id="1597"]'); ?>
```

if you're using custom shortcode then you need to pass argument for id like this :

```
function section_case_study($atts){
    ob_start();
    global $selected_id;
    $selected_id = $atts['id'];
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/section-case-study');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: The error i get. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in /data/4/5/82/84/5245736/user/6293749/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/nd-booking/inc/shortcodes/include/thankyou/nd_booking_thankyou_right_content.php on line 7

Comment: <h1 class="nd_booking_margin_top_50_responsive">'.__('Make Payment Here','nd-booking').' :</h1>
     
    function section_case_study($atts){
    ob_start();
    global $selected_id;
    $selected_id = $atts['1597'];
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/section-case-study');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
 <?php echo do_shortcode("[pff-paystack id="1597"]"); ?> 
    <div class="nd_booking_section nd_booking_height_30"></div>

Comment: Please do not post large chunks of code in comments where it cannot be properly formatted.  Edit your original question to show updates to your code.